# React js page copy and paste and refresh id not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs when i am using localhost and copy and paste the url in address bar then it will go to desired page but when i put this code to server and copy and paste it to address bar then it will redirect to loginpage

```
 const loginform = (
        <div>
            {this.state.troubleClicked ? this.props.history.push("./troublelogin") : ''}
            {this.state.dormantClicked ? this.props.history.push("./reactivatedormant") : ''}

            <div>
                <div >
                    <TabBar ref="ltabs" tabs={this.state.loginTabs} highlight="below" highlightTextColor="login_tab_text" expanded={true} callbackHandler={this.onTabClicked.bind(this)} />
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="prayer" />
                <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-user-o login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/clientid2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="none" value={this.state.userid} ref={(id) => { this.userNameRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Client ID"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-briefcase login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/password2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="off" type={"password"} value={this.state.password} ref={(id) => { this.passwordRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-id-card login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/pancard2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="off" type={"password"} value={this.state.transactionpassword} ref={(id) => { this.transPasswordRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" placeholder="PAN / TPIN / BIRTH YEAR / INCORPORATION YEAR" name="transactionpassword"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    {/* {this.state.isLoginFailed ? <div style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'red' }}><b>Sorry, Invalid credentials!</b></div> : ''} */}
                    <button type="button" className="form-control login_btn " onClick={this.startLogin}>LOGIN</button>
                    <div className='login_link'>
                        <a style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'red' }}><button className='anchor_btn' onClick={() => this.onTroubleClicked()}>Trouble Logging In?</button></a>
                        <a style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'blue' }}><button className='anchor_btn' onClick={() => this.onDormantClicked()}>Reactivate Dormant Account</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 1, color: '#ccc' }}>By Logging In, You Agree to  <a className='anchor-link'><button type="button" className="aboutus-link btn-link" onClick={this.onClickTC}>Terms&Conditions</button></a></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img style={{ height: "130px", width: "50%" }} src="assets/svg/ivl_ventures_logo.svg" alt="ivl logo"/>
                </div>
                {this.state.inProgress ? blockProgressBar() : ''}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loginStatus ? this.props.history.push("/home/dashboard") : loginform}
            <LoginTCDialog showDialog={this.state.showTCPopup} closeTCPopUp={this.onCloseTCPopUp.bind(this)} />
            <RiskDisclosureDialog showDialog={this.state.showRiskPopup} closeRDDPopUp={this.onCloseRiskPopUp.bind(this)} />
            <AdharVerificationDialog showDialog={this.state.showAdharPopup} closeAdharPopUp={this.onCloseAdharPopup} />
            {this.state.showchangepassword ?
                <ChangePassword
                    custommessage={this.state.changepasswordmessage}
                    onChangePasswordSuccess={this.onChangePasswordSuccess.bind(this)}
                    onCloseButtonClicked={this.onChangePasswordCloseClicked.bind(this)}
                    userid={this.state.userid} />
                :
                ''
            }
        </div>
    );
```

***package.json***

```
      "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start --historyApiFallback=true"
       }
```

***index.js***

```
class PreLoginPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.state = { loginStatus: this.props.loginStatus }
    this.state = {
        appversion: appReleaseVersion,
        configerror: false,
        inProgress: true
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ inProgress: true }, () => {
        this.props.getConfig((iserror) => {
            this.setState({ configerror: iserror, inProgress: false });
        });
    });
}

createAccountClicked() {
    //this.props.history.push("./createaccount");
    window.open("https://eaccount.indiabulls.com/", "_blank");
}

logoClick(){
    window.open("http://indiabullsventures.com/shubh","_blank");
}

render() {
    // var progressindicator = (
    //     <div className="progress_block_background">

    //         <svg class="circular-progress" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
    //             <circle class="circular-progress_path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20"
    //                 fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    //         </svg>

    //     </div>
    // );
    return (
        <div className='fillheight prelogin-bg'>
            <div className="row contentpanel prelogin-header-row">
                <div className="prelogin-header2 fillwidth">
                    <div className="prelogin-header-left">
                        <div className="prelogin-logo-holder">
                            <img src="assets/svg/india_bulls_logo.svg" onClick={this.logoClick.bind(this)} className="img-responsive pl-home-logo" alt="Indiabulls" style={{ marginLeft: '8px' }} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="prelogin-vdivider"> </div>
                        {/* <div className='pl-header-item'>
                            <div className='pl-small-text' >
                                <img src="assets/svg/bull.svg" style={{ width: '20px' }} /> Dial & Trade
                            </div>
                            <div className='pl-large-text' style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }} >
                                <span> {contactDetails.DIAL_AND_TRADE} </span>
                            </div>
                        </div> */}
                        <div className="prelogin-vdivider"> </div>
                        <div className='pl-header-item' >
                            <div className='pl-small-text'> <i className="fa fa-phone pl-header-icon" />Customer Care </div>
                            <div className='pl-large-text' style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} >
                                <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Open: 9:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. - Trading days"  > {contactDetails.CUSTOMER_CARE} </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="prelogin-vdivider"> </div>
                        <div className='pl-header-item' >
                            <div className='pl-small-text'> <i className="fa fa-inbox pl-header-icon" />Email ID</div>
                            <div className='pl-large-text' style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} >{contactDetails.HELPDESK_EMAIL}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="pl-header-item btnholder">
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row contentpanel prelogin-content-row">
                <div className="prelogin-content2 fillwidth">
                    <div className="pl-content-parent2">
                        <div className="pl-content-holder2">
                            <div className='pl-poster2'>
                                <div id="loginCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                                    <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li href="#loginCarousel" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                                        <li href="#loginCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    </ol>
                                    <div className="carousel-inner" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                                        <div className="carousel-item active" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                                            <img src='assets/images/slider_1.JPG' style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }} alt="slider"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="carousel-item" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                                            <img src='assets/images/slider_3.JPG' style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }} alt="slider"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="login_mainholder2">

                                {this.state.inProgress || this.state.configerror ?
                                    <Loading inProgress={this.state.inProgress} configerror={this.state.configerror} />
                                    :
                                    <center>
                                        <div className="form-group login_form">
                                            <Switch>
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/login`} exact component={LoginPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/setpassword`} exact component={SetPasswordPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/forgotpassword`} exact component={ForgotPasswordPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/forgottpin`} exact component={ForgotTPINPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/retriveclientid`} exact component={RetriveClientIdPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/unlockaccount`} exact component={UnlockAccountPage} />
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/troubleLogin`} exact component={TroubleLoggingIn} />
                                                {/* <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/createaccount`} exact component={CreateAccountPage} /> */}
                                                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/reactivatedormant`} exact component={ReactivateDormant} />
                                                <Redirect to="/base/login" />
                                            </Switch>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                                }

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}
 }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {

}
}


  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
return {
    getConfig: (callback) => getConfig(dispatch, callback),
    watchListGroupAction: () => watchListGroupAction(dispatch),
};
};

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PreLoginPage);
```

***troublelogin.js***

```
    import React from 'react';


 class TroubleLoggingIn extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        form: 'forgotpassword',
        status: false,
    }
    }
     onButtonClick(e) {
        this.setState({ status: true, form: e.target.value });
     }
render() {
    const troubleform = (
        <div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: 20, color: '#000' }}>
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Trouble Logging In</div>
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 12, color: '#ccc' }}>We will help you to recover your ClientID or Password.
                       </div>
            </div>





            </div>
        </div>

    )
    return (
        <div className="fillheight">
            {this.state.status ? this.props.history.push("./" + this.state.form) : troubleform}
        </div>
    )
}

  }

   export default TroubleLoggingIn;
```

***index.js*** (for login it has different package from above index.js)

```
  import React from "react";
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
 import { submitLogin, setLoginStatus, afterSuccessLogin, afterFailedLogin,    submitLogout, setToLogout, setSessionCheck } from '../../../actions/login/submitLogin'
  import { getConfig } from '../../../actions/common'
  import { getItemByKey } from '../../../common/utils'
  import { localStorageKeys, ModuleKeys,ReleaseEnvironment } from '../../../common/constants'
  import { watchListGroupAction } from '../../../actions/watchlist/watchlistaction'
  import { isValidUserName, isValidLoginPassword, isValidLoginTPIN } from '../../../validators/loginValidations'
  import TabBar from "../../../controls/TabBar";
  import LoginTCDialog from '../../../controls/prelogin/LoginTermsAndCondition'
  import RiskDisclosureDialog from '../../../controls/prelogin/RiskDisclosurePopup'
 import AdharVerificationDialog from '../../../controls/prelogin/Adharverification'
import { showErrorDialog } from '../../../actions/orderentry/orderentryaction'
import ChangePassword from '../../../components/settings/ChangePassword'
import { setExpandWidget } from '../../../actions/dashboard'
import { blockProgressBar } from '../../../controls/progress'
import {loginWarning} from '../../../actions/login/submitLogin'

 class LoginPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userid: '',
        password: '',
        transactionpassword: '',
        inProgress: false,
        loginTabs: ['SHUBH WEB'],
        selectedsegment: 'SHUBH WEB',
        showTCPopup: false,
        showRiskPopup: false,
        showAdharPopup: false,
        troubleClicked: false,
        dormantClicked: false,
        isLoginFailed: false,
        loginStatus: false,
        showchangepassword: false,
        changepasswordmessage: '',
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    this.startLogin = this.startLogin.bind(this);
    this.onClickTC = this.onClickTC.bind(this);
    this.onCloseAdharPopup = this.onCloseAdharPopup.bind(this);
    this.onTroubleClicked = this.onTroubleClicked.bind(this);
    this.onDormantClicked = this.onDormantClicked.bind(this);
}


componentWillMount() {
    var status = getItemByKey(localStorageKeys.LOGIN_STATUS);
    if (status) {
        this.props.setLoginStatus();
        this.props.watchListGroupAction();
        this.setState({ loginStatus: true })
    } else {
        this.props.setLoginStatus(false);
    }
    //window.socketEvents.disconnect();
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.userNameRef)
        this.userNameRef.focus();

    console.log(this.props.tologout);
    if (this.props.tologout) {
        submitLogout();
        this.props.setToLogout(false);
    }

}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.loginStatus !== this.state.loginStatus) {
        this.setState({ loginStatus: nextProps.loginStatus })
    }
}


setValue(key, value) {
    this.setState((state) => {
        let newValue = {}
        if(key === "userid"){
            newValue[key] = value.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            newValue[key] = value;
        }
        return Object.assign({}, state, newValue)
    })
}

onChange(e) {
    let { target: { name, value } } = e;
    this.setValue(name, value);
}

onKeyPress(e) {
    let { target: { name } } = e;
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        if (name === 'userid')
            this.passwordRef.focus();
        else if (name === 'password')
            this.transPasswordRef.focus();
        else if (name === 'transactionpassword')
            this.startLogin();
    }
}


startLogin() {
    var error;
    error = isValidUserName(this.state.userid)
    if (error !== '') {
        this.props.showErrorDialog({ header: "Error", message: error });
        return;
    }

    error = isValidLoginPassword(this.state.password);
    if (error !== '') {
        this.props.showErrorDialog({ header: "Error", message: error });
        return;
    }

    error = isValidLoginTPIN(this.state.transactionpassword);
    if (error !== '') {
        this.props.showErrorDialog({ header: "Error", message: error });
        return;
    }

    var panTpin = this.state.transactionpassword.toUpperCase();

    var requestData = {
        request: {
            data: {
                userid: this.state.userid,
                password: this.state.password,
                panTpin: panTpin
            }
        }
    }
    this.setState({ inProgress: true });
    submitLogin(requestData, this.loginSuccessCallback.bind(this), this.loginFailedCallback.bind(this));
}

loginSuccessCallback(responseData) {
    console.log(responseData)
    this.setState({ inProgress: false });
    this.props.setSessionCheck();
    this.props.setExpandWidget(ModuleKeys.ALL);
    var accdet = (responseData.response.data.accountDetails);
    if(responseData.response.infoID === 'EGN011'){
        let warningData = {loginwarningMsg:responseData.response.infoMsg,showLoginWarningDialog:true,redirectLink:responseData.response.data.url}
        this.props.loginWarning(warningData);
    }
    else if (accdet.firstLogin) {
        this.setState({ showchangepassword: true, changepasswordmessage: 'Please set new Password', password: '', transactionpassword: '' });
    }
    else if (accdet.passwordExpired) {
        this.setState({ showchangepassword: true, changepasswordmessage: 'Your password is expired. Please set new Password.', password: '', transactionpassword: '' });
    }
    else if (accdet.passwordReset && accdet.passwordReset === "Y") {
        this.setState({ showchangepassword: true, changepasswordmessage: 'Please set new Password.', password: '', transactionpassword: '' });
    }
    else {
        this.props.afterSuccessLogin(responseData);
    }
}

loginFailedCallback(responseData) {
    this.setState({ inProgress: false, isLoginFailed: true, userid: '', password: '', transactionpassword: '' });
    this.props.afterFailedLogin({ header: "Error", message: responseData.message });
}

onChangePasswordSuccess() {
    this.setState({ showchangepassword: false });
}

onChangePasswordCloseClicked() {
    this.setState({ showchangepassword: false });
}

onTabClicked(tabName) {
    switch (tabName) {
        case "SHUBH WEB":
            this.setState({ selectedsegment: 'SHUBH WEB' });
            break;
        case "CLASSIC WEBSITE":
            //this.setState({ selectedsegment: "CLASSIC WEBSITE" });
            this.refs.ltabs.setActiveTab("SHUBH WEB");
            window.open("https://trade.indiabulls.com/login/login.htm", "_blank")
            break;
        default:break;
    }
}

onTroubleClicked() {
    console.log('trouble clicked');
    this.setState({ troubleClicked: true });
}

onDormantClicked() {
    console.log('dormant clicked');
    this.setState({ dormantClicked: true });
    //window.open("https://trade.indiabulls.com/dormant/reactivateClient.jsp", "_blank");
}
onCloseTCPopUp() {
    this.setState({ showTCPopup: false });
}

onCloseRiskPopUp() {
    this.setState({ showRiskPopup: false });
}

onCloseAdharPopup() {
    console.log("close adhar popup");
    this.setState({ showAdharPopup: false });
}
onClickTC() {
    this.setState({ showTCPopup: true });
    // this.setState({ showAdharPopup: true });
}
render() {
    // var progressindicator = (
    //     <div className="progress_block_background">

    //         <svg class="circular-progress" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
    //             <circle class="circular-progress_path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20"
    //                 fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    //         </svg>

    //     </div>
    // );

    const loginform = (
        <div>
            {this.state.troubleClicked ? this.props.history.push("./troublelogin") : ''}
            {this.state.dormantClicked ? this.props.history.push("./reactivatedormant") : ''}

            <div>
                <div >
                    <TabBar ref="ltabs" tabs={this.state.loginTabs} highlight="below" highlightTextColor="login_tab_text" expanded={true} callbackHandler={this.onTabClicked.bind(this)} />
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="prayer" />
                <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-user-o login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/clientid2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="none" value={this.state.userid} ref={(id) => { this.userNameRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Client ID"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-briefcase login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/password2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="off" type={"password"} value={this.state.password} ref={(id) => { this.passwordRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='icon_style'>
                        {/* <span className="fa fa-id-card login_icon "></span> */}
                        <img className="login_icon" src="assets/images/pancard2.png" alt="login"/>
                        <input autoComplete="off" type={"password"} value={this.state.transactionpassword} ref={(id) => { this.transPasswordRef = id; }}
                            onChange={this.onChange} onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyPress(e)} maxLength="12"
                            className="form-control login_formcontrol" placeholder="PAN / TPIN / BIRTH YEAR / INCORPORATION YEAR" name="transactionpassword"
                            onPaste={e=>e.preventDefault()}></input>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" className="form-control login_btn " onClick={this.startLogin}>LOGIN</button>
                    <div className='login_link'>
                        <a style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'red' }}><button className='anchor_btn' onClick={() => this.onTroubleClicked()}>Trouble Logging In?</button></a>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <img style={{ height: "130px", width: "50%" }} src="assets/svg/ivl_ventures_logo.svg" alt="ivl logo"/>
                </div>
                {this.state.inProgress ? blockProgressBar() : ''}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loginStatus ? this.props.history.push("/home/dashboard") : loginform}
            <LoginTCDialog showDialog={this.state.showTCPopup} closeTCPopUp={this.onCloseTCPopUp.bind(this)} />
            <RiskDisclosureDialog showDialog={this.state.showRiskPopup} closeRDDPopUp={this.onCloseRiskPopUp.bind(this)} />
            <AdharVerificationDialog showDialog={this.state.showAdharPopup} closeAdharPopUp={this.onCloseAdharPopup} />
            {this.state.showchangepassword ?
                <ChangePassword
                    custommessage={this.state.changepasswordmessage}
                    onChangePasswordSuccess={this.onChangePasswordSuccess.bind(this)}
                    onCloseButtonClicked={this.onChangePasswordCloseClicked.bind(this)}
                    userid={this.state.userid} />
                :
                ''
            }
        </div>
      );
     };
   }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.loginStatus)
     return {
       loginStatus: state.loginStatus.status,
         tologout: state.loginStatus.tologout
    }
   }


  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
      return {
       login: ({ userid, password, transactionpassword }) => submitLogin(dispatch),
    afterFailedLogin: (errordata) => afterFailedLogin(dispatch, errordata),
    afterSuccessLogin: (responseData) => afterSuccessLogin(dispatch, responseData),
    getConfig: () => getConfig(dispatch),
    setLoginStatus: (status) => setLoginStatus(dispatch, status),
    watchListGroupAction: () => watchListGroupAction(dispatch),
    showErrorDialog: (errordata) => showErrorDialog(dispatch, errordata),
    setToLogout: (tologout) => setToLogout(dispatch, tologout),
    setSessionCheck: () => setSessionCheck(dispatch, false),
    setExpandWidget: (activeWidget) => setExpandWidget(activeWidget, dispatch),
    loginWarning : (warningData) => loginWarning(dispatch,warningData)
};
 };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Well, how do you set `this.state.loginStatus`? Have you checked to see its value on the server?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Herbst home/dashboard is not related to url it will used when user succefully logged problem is that when i copy and paste serverip/base/troublelogging URl in address bar this will redirect to serverip/base/login and trublelogging does not require loginStatus value because it does not require authentication for opening the page

Comment: it is working for localhost and not working for server

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell the value of `this.state.loginStatus` determines if your code sends the user to the login page. So unless you have other code that you haven't shown us, clearly that code path is being fired, likely because the value of `this.state.loginStatus` on the server is not what you expect it to be. So again, how is `this.state.loginStatus` set?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst i have updated it

Comment: @MatthewHerbst problem is still open can anyone suggest so i can go through it

Comment: because it is working perfectly in localhost but problem occurs on server  this code deployed on server but perfectly on localhost

Comment: can you tell us what server are you using to run your react app?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of server are you running? is it Apache? Nginx? Node?
each server needs to be configured to work properly with React history (urls).

What needs to be done is to configure your server for 404 page fallback redirect to your main index.html file, so whenever the server cannot find the file / url path, instead of redirecting to some error.html / 404.html it should redirect back to index.html.

small read regarding the issue:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20774914/Redirecting-HTTP-404-error-to-Customize-page-in-weblogic-Portal.html

Comment: we are using weblogic server

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the solution?

Comment: I think you did not understand my question please read it .I am not asking about redirection on error 404 .Please read my question